# Iphone Running Using Performance Tool

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone

I run my program using Object Allocations Performance Tool. My program is a really simple program which has a simple AtlasSprite object. Just it ! but I wached the allocations and it's allocations is always increasing in spite of doing nothing ! any idea !?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you have a loop that is allocating objects but not releasing them. Can't know unless you post the code.

Comment: I don't have my code right now but I'll post it ASAP. But i don't have any loops in my program. It's just a simple initialization of AtlasSprite and AtlasAnimation.

Comment: If you're using cocos2d then you most certainly have a loop in your app in the form of the game loop.